# How to change the default directory in RStudio Server?

Tags: rstudio, rstudio-server

By default RStudio-Server displays the contents of the Home (~) directory in the Files frame. Where does it load that frame? And how can it be changed so that it takes up a user specific directory?

Update: Kindly note, I was talking about changing the settings in RSTUDIO-SERVER edition. May be some JS or some code would load the working directory; I want that part of the code.

Comment: Help to close the below one as recommended answer - if it solves your problem

Comment: @RUser Sorry, I was talking about the RSTUDIO-Server edition. So when it loads, it shows a particular directory. Updated the question for better clarity

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools | Global Options` - you will see the default directory.

[image]

or  `Session -> Set Working Directory -> Choose Directory`

[image]

Or you can set your working directory on console like that

```
setwd("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/R")
```

Comment: I get the impression that they wanted Rstudio Server to startup in that directory.